# How to build Sql query in Javascript

Tags: javascript, t-sql

I am facing problems in building Sql query in Javascript. I used the case statement in my Sql query.

The below is the query to be used to bring the results,
It is written in Javascript function inside an .aspx page.
And i have used the Sql case statement inside it.

```
sqlInit1 = 'SELECT Distinct A.CR_LAST_UPDATE, Case When b.ca_vote = 'Approve' and b.ca_title='RSM' Then b.ca_email When b.ca_vote = 'Reject' Then '' When b.ca_vote = 'Pending' Then '' When b.ca_vote = 'IN PROCESS' Then '' End as CA_EMAIL FROM CREDIT A INNER JOIN CREDIT_APPROVALS B ON A.CR_ID = B.C_ID WHERE ';
```

Whenever i open the webpage, it is giving error.
Please let me how to format this. So that it will give a good result.

Comment: Your query just ends with the word `WHERE` which definitely seems incorrect. But what error are you getting?

Comment: If you deploy this, it's only a matter of time before someone ownz your database server. :( sql and client javascript shouldn't mix.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Isn't it fair to assume that he'll be tacking on some where clauses further down in the script? Anyhow the question wasn't how to write sql, but how to avoid javascript throwing an error while building it.

Comment: @Mithon - The question itself doesn't reveal anything about the nature of the error (omitting useful details like what the error message actually says!). I hadn't noticed the single quotes issue so it might equally have been a SQL syntax one.

Comment: Ait, maybe I was assuming to much. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You're ending your query string at the ca_vote. To avoid this use double quotes for the query string, and single quotes for the inner strings in sql. Like this:

```
sqlInit1 = "SELECT Distinct A.CR_LAST_UPDATE, Case When b.ca_vote = 'Approve' and b.ca_title='RSM' Then b.ca_email When b.ca_vote = 'Reject' Then '' When b.ca_vote = 'Pending' Then '' When b.ca_vote = 'IN PROCESS' Then '' End as CA_EMAIL FROM CREDIT A INNER JOIN CREDIT_APPROVALS B ON A.CR_ID = B.C_ID WHERE ";
```

I'm not even going to ask why you want to place SQL in your javascript.. :)

Edit: Ok. So now that you got that working, but having trouble with sql syntax, here's the reference for the [Case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in T-SQL (the SQL-dialect used for Microsoft SQL Server). Shows you the spec and numerous examples.

Comment: No, I think we *indeed* need to ask why the OP is putting SQL in the Javascript...

Comment: @KirkWoll Well, it was a pretty obvious hint that the OP should think about what he's doing. If he doesn't take the hint, it's a lost cause, and I'll resign to simply trying to help him do whatever basic javascripting. Remember, everybody starts somewhere, and chances are they'll figure out why this is a bad idea. Hopefully before placing this in some customer site.. :)

Comment: I know.  My comment was not to you, but rather to the OP and SO at large. :)

Comment: Anybody please let me know how to avoid the error..

Comment: The application is working fine, but i need to add Sql case statement in the query..i am getting error on this..please help me in this.

Comment: @user170448 - This answer tells you what's wrong with the parsing of the script: you need to use `var x = "..."` when declaring a variable using `'` in a string, or escape the `\'` in the string.